# Confusions about TypeScript Promise return type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following code in TypeScript React:

```
const AirQuality= async ():Promise<string>=>{
    console.log('Air Quality')
    let data = await fetch(url,{
        method:'GET',
        // mode:'no-cors'
    })
    return data.json()
}
```

As you can see here, `data.json()`was returned from the function. The thing I don't get is why I am not getting an error when I define the Promise type as string. What is the issue here? I changed Promise type to number, still, no error is shown. What could be the cause for that?

Comment: The type `ReturnType<Response['json']>` is `Promise<any>` which is assignable to both `Promise<string>` and `Promise<number>`. You should narrow the type based on what you know about the remote endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json()` parses the returned JSON into a JavaScript object structure. Since this can be any kind of object depending on what the server returns, it has the type `Promise<any>`.

An `any` type can be converted to anything including number or string, which is why you don't see an error.